# SQLite what type of value returned by sqlite3_column_text?

Tags: c++, sqlite

i try  to make simple auth system.  its part  of server code:

```
void ClientHandler(int index) {
        strstr << "SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='" << login1 << "'" << " AND password='" << password1 << "'";
        std::string str = strstr.str();
        char* db_name = "users.db";
        sqlite3* db;
        char* zErrMsg = 0;
        int error;
        sqlite3_stmt* res;
        const char* tail;
        error = sqlite3_open(db_name, &db);
        if (error)
        {
            cout << "Can't open database: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }

        error = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, str.c_str(), 1000, &res, &tail);
        if (error)
        {
            cout << "Can't select data: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }

        cout << "Display result from table1" << endl;
        int     rec_count = 0;
        while (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            cout << sqlite3_column_int64(res, 0) << endl;

            //rec_count++;
        }
        if (sqlite3_column_text(res, 0) != NULL)

        { //  GOOD

            int msg_size = msg2.size();
            send(Connections[index], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
            send(Connections[index], msg2.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
            std::cout << msg2 << std::endl;
        }
        { //  BAD
            int msg_size = msg3.size();
            send(Connections[index], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
            send(Connections[index], msg3.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
            std::cout << msg3 << std::endl;
        }

            delete[] msg;
}
```

In this part i whant to check is log/pass correct (by finding ID).

```
 if (sqlite3_column_text(res, 0) != NULL)

        { //  GOOD
            int msg_size = msg2.size();
            send(Connections[index], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
            send(Connections[index], msg2.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
            std::cout << msg2 << std::endl;
        }
        { //  BAD
            int msg_size = msg3.size();
            send(Connections[index], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
            send(Connections[index], msg3.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
            std::cout << msg3 << std::endl;
        }
```

But i cant understand what type of data return `sqlite3_column_text` (when log/pass incorect he return nothing?)
How i can make this if/else statement correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sql statement you select some "id" from the table users, where the login and password data should be equal.

So, it will only return an id, if such an record is found. `sqlite3_step(res)` will then return `SQLITE_ROW`. And here you need to check. Either the password is correct or not. At least if you have unique IDs and unique logins, which is a must.

Then you need to rewite your code to something like

```
if (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW)
{   //  GOOD

    cout << sqlite3_column_int64(res, 0) << endl;

    int msg_size = msg2.size();
    send(Connections[index], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
    send(Connections[index], msg2.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
    std::cout << msg2 << std::endl;
}
else
{   //  BAD
    int msg_size = msg3.size();
    send(Connections[index], (char*)& msg_size, sizeof(int), NULL);
    send(Connections[index], msg3.c_str(), msg_size, NULL);
    std::cout << msg3 << std::endl;
}
```

You should not call `if (sqlite3_column_text(res, 0) != NULL)`. MOst probaly you iid ist an int64. No need to get it as string again.

By the way `sqlite3_column_text(res, 0)` would return a char* to a null terminated string. >ou just need to write something like `char* idtext = sqlite3_column_text(res, 0)`. But only, if a record could be read!

Always check the return values!

Caveat! Too much of your code is unknown to me, so I cannot judge completely. . .